# XML not being parsed as expected in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml file as follows

```
<Moves>
  <Move name="left">
     <Coord X="100" Y="100"/>
     <Coord X="50" Y="100"/>
  </Move>
  <Move name="right">
     <Coord X="10" Y="80"/>
     <Coord X="40" Y="90"/>
  </Move>
<Moves>
```

I am parsing it in Java using SAX Parser. the following two methods parse it basically

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Coord")){
                    X = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("X"));
                    Y = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("Y"));
                } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Move")) {
                    move_points.clear();
                    move_name = attributes.getValue("name");
                }
            }

            /* If the read element is Move, add a MoveList with the name and if it is
             * a Coord, create a Point with it.
             */
            @Override
            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Coord")){
                    move_points.add(new Points(X, Y));
                } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Move")) {
                    moves_list.add(new MovesList(move_name, move_points));
                }
          }
```

I have an ArrayList move_points that stores all the coords read and an Arraylist moves_list that stores the moves name and their coords (which is an arraylist - move_points here)

The problem i am having is that when the document is parsed all the elements that are inside moves_list have the correct name but the entry in move_points or the coord stored are that of the last move in the XML file.

when i am checking what is being entered into moves_list in endElement method after each element Move, it shows the correct coord being entered into moves_list but when the whole document is parsed and i view what is inside moves_list after the root element Moves has been parsed,  i am getting moves_list with all the coords of that of the last move.

Please help me out.

PS. moves_list is a public static variable

MovesList Class

```
public class MovesList {

private ArrayList<Points> move_points;
private String move_name;

public MovesList (String move_name, ArrayList<Points> move_points) {
    this.move_name = move_name;
    this.move_points = move_points;
}

public String getName(){
    return move_name;
}

public ArrayList<Points> getPoints(){
    return move_points;
}
```

}

Points Class

```
public class Points extends Point {

private int X;
private int Y;

public Points (int X, int Y) {
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
}

public Points (Points p) {
    X = p.getIntX();
    Y = p.getIntY();
}

public int getIntX () {
    return X;
}

public int getIntY () {
    return Y;
}

}
```

Comment: You should really have no static variables, only when essential (and nothing above suggests an essential need), and in fact this can mess you up, for instance if your Points class uses static varibles for x and y, you're doomed to have this problem.

Comment: Points class does not have static X and Y instead as you can see i create a new Point object every time a Coord is read

Comment: Please show your MovesList and Points class code. I'm still betting on some errant static variable.

Comment: What's `X`? What's `Y`? Why is a single point named `Points`?

Comment: (In other words, if they're static, saying the `Points` class is "similar" isn't enough to diagnose the likely problem. HFoE is likely correct; that's why we ask the questions we ask.)

Comment: ok its done now, The point class is here

Comment: because it extended the Point Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you don't create a new move_points object. So this:

```
} else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Move")) {
  move_points.clear();
  move_name = attributes.getValue("name");
}
```

Should be this:

```
} else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Move")) {
  move_points = new ArrayList<Points>(); // note difference
  move_name = attributes.getValue("name");
}
```

Otherwise each MovesList object will have a move_points variable that refers to the same object.

Comment: Yes it does it.....but i still dont get the problem, i was creating a new moves_list object with moves_points before clearing it, how did they point to the same object

Comment: @Shivam: A new object is only created if you actually do something to create it such as using the new key word or call some factory method (if one exists). Otherwise if you don't create a new ArrayList, then you will keep passing the very same ArrayList into the MovesList constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you have a variable named move_points, and when you create a new MovesList, you use a variable named points.  is that a typo?  also, since you seem to share move_points and clear it when you start a new Move element, i hope you are copying the List when creating the MovesList.

Comment: thats a typo.....what i did is, i added move_points to the move_list when the move element is done. when it is again read i cleared move_points so that there is no previous point in the array an it starts afresh

Comment: @ShivamShah: please fix your typos (now) and only post real code. It's hard enough trying to understand others' code that you should strive not to make it harder.